# sql: want to select record from table 1, based on matching (or no matching) record in table2

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables. They are linked together with a userid. What i wanted do is check if there's a linked record in table 2 AND if a date field in that table is older then a certain time OR if there's no linked record in the 2nd table.

I thought i wanted a left join, but it's ignoring the date field. If there are no records in the 2nd table, then i want to ignore the 2nd table. But if there is a matching record in the 2nd table and the date is outside of my range, then i dont want to select those records.

```
SELECT FirstName, Email, u.userid FROM u
LEFT JOIN uevh
ON u.UserID = uevh.UserID AND uevh.LastEmailed < GETDATE()-14
WHERE u.ConfirmedEmail = 0
```

if i run that, and there's a record in the uevh table that's less then 14 days old, i dont want a record returned, but it's returning a record regardless of the date.

Comment: made a small bit of progress - switched the join around so it's joining table 2 on table 1 - now when i select, when it should return no records, it's instead returning a record but with null values in the fields.

Comment: At least provide the SQL query you have created so far.

Comment: sorry about that - i included the sql query i'm currently using

Comment: That wont work, because if there's no matching record in uevh, then i get no records. If there's no matching records in uevh, but there is a record in u, then i should get the record from U

Comment: And what if, for a certain user, there are records in `uevh`, both older and newer than 14 days old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.FirstName
     , u.Email
     , u.userid 
FROM u
WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM uevh
          WHERE u.UserID = uevh.UserID
            AND NOT (uevh.LastEmailed < GETDATE()-14)
        )
  AND u.ConfirmedEmail = 0
```

or:

```
SELECT u.FirstName
     , u.Email
     , u.userid 
FROM u
WHERE ( EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM uevh
          WHERE u.UserID = uevh.UserID
            AND uevh.LastEmailed < GETDATE()-14
        )
     OR NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM uevh
          WHERE u.UserID = uevh.UserID
        )
      )
  AND u.ConfirmedEmail = 0
```

or:

```
SELECT u.FirstName
     , u.Email
     , u.userid 
FROM u
  LEFT JOIN uevh
    ON u.UserID = uevh.UserID 
WHERE u.ConfirmedEmail = 0
  AND ( uevh.LastEmailed < GETDATE()-14
     OR uehv.UserID IS NULL
      )
```

Comment: #3 is what I was going to post.

Comment: #3 is the one i went with, thank you for the answer and for showing me multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: They are not exactly multiple ways but yield slightly different results as well. Try them with a small data set, so you see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. This is untested but should work.

```
Declare @date datetime;
Set @date='20110101';

Select *
from tbl1 
Left outer join tbl2 on tbl1.Id =tbl2.Id
  and @date > coalesce(tbl2.date,dateadd(day,1,@date));
```